# How to create a Rust type that can hold either an integer or a pointer within the size of a single word?

Tags: pointers, optimization, rust, ocaml, union-types

(I’m referring to boxing as a way to distinguish integers and pointers at runtime. A technique used some programming languages to aid GC like [OCaml](https://v1.realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/memory-representation-of-values.html#distinguishing-integer-and-pointers-at-runtime). Not the Rust `Box<T>` type.)

I have a Rust enum that looks like this:

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug, PartialEq)]
enum Type<'ts> {
    TVar(usize),
    Constructed(&'ts ConstructedType<'ts>),
}
```

As I understand it the memory layout for this enum will be two words. One for the tag and one for the payload. I would like to fit the memory in a single word if possible.

Languages like [OCaml](https://v1.realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/memory-representation-of-values.html#distinguishing-integer-and-pointers-at-runtime) use a technique called “integer boxing” which takes advantage of the fact that pointers are aligned. This means that the lowest bit will be 0. If you shift the bits in your integer one space to the left and set the lowest bit of your integer to 1 then you’re using that bit as a tag at the cost of one bit of integer precision.

Are Rust pointers guaranteed to be aligned? How would I implement this technique for my type in Rust?

Comment: "If you shift the bits in your integer one space to the left and set the lowest bit of your integer to 1 then you’re using that bit as a tag at the cost of one bit of integer precision.", yes but that not the purpose of usize, plus, do this with a address would be totally implementation defined. This is AFAIK not recommended with Rust because totally unsafe to do.

Comment: Plus this come with a runtime cost: "An even more alert reader will be wondering about the performance implications are for integer arithmetic using this tagged representation. Since the bottom bit is set, any operation on the integer has to shift the bottom bit right to recover the "native" value. The native code OCaml compiler generates efficient x86 assembly code in this case, taking advantage of modern processor instructions to hide the extra shifts where possible. Addition is a single LEA x86 instruction, subtraction can be two instructions, and multiplication is only a few more."

Comment: But I think it's possible if you use raw pointer and raw enum (aka C enum) but as I said this will not be very portable, and I think that unless you work on an embedded system, "safe" a little of memory space like this is not worth it.

Comment: I understand the safety/runtime implications. I wanted to know how it could be done to see if this optimization works well for my program. But you’re probably right in that I’m trying to optimize. Thanks for providing some reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I may not be following *everything* you are saying, but I think you need a `union`.

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug, PartialEq)]
enum Type<'ts> {
    TVar(usize),
    Constructed(&'ts ConstructedType<'ts>),
}

union CompactType<'ts> {
    num: usize,
    ptr: &'ts ConstructedType<'ts>
}

impl<'ts> From<CompactType<'ts>> for Type<'ts> {
    fn from(compact: CompactType<'ts>) -> Type<'ts> {
        unsafe {
            if compact.num & 1 == 1 {
                Type::TVar(compact.num >> 1)
            } else {
                Type::Constructed(compact.ptr)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that accessing members of a `union` is unsafe, and you have to make sure that all invariants are enforced. For example, you have to explicitly check that the `CompactType`s are correctly created with the values within range, and prevent the possibility of the objects being constructed without being subject to those checks.

I would suggest adding constructor functions to `CompactType`, which return a `Result` or an `Option`, in case you try to use a number that is too large or a pointer to a type that is not properly aligned. When the [`TryFrom` feature](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.TryFrom.html) stabilizes, you could use that, but in the meantime:

```
enum CompactConvertError {
    NumTooBig(String),
    PtrNotAligned(String),
}

impl<'ts> Type<'ts> {
    fn to_compact(&self) -> Result<CompactType<'ts>, CompactConvertError> {
        match self {
            Type::TVar(num) => {
                if num >> (mem::size_of::<usize>() * 8 - 1) == 1 {
                    Err(CompactConvertError::NumTooBig(
                        String::from("The last bit of the usize cannot be used here"))
                    )
                } else {
                    Ok(CompactType { num: num << 1 | 1usize })
                }   
            },
            Type::Constructed(c) => {
                if mem::align_of_val(*c) % 2 == 1 {
                    Err(CompactConvertError::PtrNotAligned(
                        String::from("The pointer must be to a type with even alignment"))
                    )
                } else {
                    Ok(CompactType { ptr: c })
                }
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

This should be flexible enough to replace `ConstructedType` with a generic type parameter. The only restriction is that you shouldn't change it from a reference to an owned value, or else you'll have to worry about dropping it correctly — which cannot yet be done for a `union` type in stable Rust.

As for alignment, if `ConstructedType` is only 1 byte in size, you will need to add an alignment to it, to make sure it is only on an even byte, otherwise Rust may choose to pack them more tightly:

```
#[align(2)]
struct ConstructedType<'ts> { 
    // ...
}
```

Definitely don't add `#[align(2)]` if the size is larger than 2 bytes. Perhaps someone else can offer advice on making that part more robust.

Comment: Alignment can be checked with `std::mem::align_of()`, so that could be used as an assertion.

Comment: @Kornel Yep. But I'm not sure how to restrict the alignment on the struct itself, without picking a fixed value.

Comment: I tried an approach like this but ran into two questions: 1) am I breaking any guarantees of the borrow checker? Will ConstructedType be dropped leaving me with a dangling pointer? 2) can I implement Copy on my union? Since I’m migrating code from the previous implementation which heavily relies on Copy.

Comment: @Calebmer As far as I can tell, there is no need to do anything about dropping the values since you do not own any data except a `usize`. (It is not yet stabilised for unions to implement `Drop` anyway).

Comment: I can't see a problem with implementing `Copy`. What is your concern?

Comment: At least when I tried `#[derive(Copy)]` I could not then copy the union value. Is this a known limitation?

Comment: @Calebmer I don't know of a limitation like that. See this [more complete code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=f65cdb3c20121a6b48c6290989e2001b&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015). It has a value being copied near the end (commented).

Comment: `TryFrom` is stable — care to show how it might be used? (Feel free to flag this comment once you've addressed it).